# Android HTTP Get and Result String

Tags: android, http-get

I'm new to the android side of development, and one thing that I know that I wanted to try out was how to use HTTP Get. I've got the whole method setup so that the text is sent and my results come back in a string, but what I wanted to know was how to I take that string and extract just the parts I really need. for example the string comes back with

```
{"id":"124343","name":"somename" }
```

and if I just wanted to get the id part of that start how would I do that in android. I'm searching through the docs, but so far I haven't really found anything and then most of what I do find revolves around using JSON as well.

Below is the code I'm currently using (which I've compiled together from several different posts) but maybe I need to switch to using JSON for parsing purposes and I'm just not sure where to make that change

```
     //This class is called after a button is pressed and the HTTPGet string is compiled from text within a textview and a static string (this already works)
     private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        int n = 1;
        while (n > 0) {
            byte[] b = new byte[4096];
            n = in.read(b);
            if (n > 0)
                out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
        }
        return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        String question = questionText.getText().toString();
        String newString = httpPath + "?userText=" + question;
        Log.i("Message", newString);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(newString);
        String text = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                    localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return text;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results != null) {
            Log.i("String", results);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to extract data from JSON string

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(YourJSONString);
String id = obj.getString("id");
String name = obj.getString("name");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, right now I'm not using JSON so is there another way to do this without JSON or should I switch over to using JSON for parsing purposes? I'll update the post with my code

Comment: This is what I needed to do, just turn the result string into a JSON object since it was already formatted that way and then I was able to extract what I needed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want::

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(newString);
String text = null;
    try {
          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
          InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

          while ((text = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

              //Work with "text" here...
             //Split the string as you wish with "text.split();" function..

             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
         }
```